# How to make contents covered till now slide in beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I would like to have a table of contents slide (in beamer) initially,
but after each major section is covered I would like to have a
table of contents slide which just shows all contents that are
covered till now and the next content! (and not the whole table
of contents slide)

How to do this?

Comment: It would be better if your questions would include a minimal working example. For example for this question it was extreeeeeeeeeeeemly boring to create a test document, adding sections etc. - that's stuff you could do yourself to make it easier for people to work on a solution for you!

Comment: Sure! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}<\value{section}>
        \tableofcontents[pausesections]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\maketitle\end{frame}

\section{SECT I}

\subsection{I.1}
\begin{frame}I.1\end{frame}

\subsection{I.2}
\begin{frame}I.2\end{frame}

\section{SECT II}
\begin{frame}II frame 1\end{frame}
\begin{frame}II frame 2\end{frame}

\section{SECT III}
\subsection{III.1}
\begin{frame}III.1\end{frame}

\subsection{III.2}
\begin{frame}III.2\end{frame}

\end{document}
```